# Qual função no R para reordenar um data.frame que contém dados ausentes (NA)?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho o seguinte `data.frame`:

```
Linha   Data    Total    Med.2    DP.2   Med.3    DP.3   Med.4    DP.4
1       2009    1.4749      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       2010    2.9945  2.2347  1.0746      NA      NA      NA      NA
3       2011    2.9945  2.9945  0.0000  2.4880  0.8774      NA      NA
4       2012    3.0000  2.9973  0.0039  2.9963  0.0032  2.6160  0.7607
5       2013    2.9973  2.9986  0.0019  2.9973  0.0027  2.9966  0.0026
6       2014    2.9973  2.9973  0.0000  2.9982  0.0016  2.9973  0.0022
```

Preciso reordenar as linhas do `data.frame` de acordo com a informação da coluna `Med.2`. Como posso realizar este procedimento utilizando o **R**?

> Obs: Tentei empregar as funções `order` do pacote base e `arrange` do pacote `dplyr`, mas em ambas obtive um resultado errado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lendo os seus dados:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Linha   Data    Total    Med.2    DP.2   Med.3    DP.3   Med.4    DP.4
                          1       2009    1.4749      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
                          2       2010    2.9945  2.2347  1.0746      NA      NA      NA      NA
                          3       2011    2.9945  2.9945  0.0000  2.4880  0.8774      NA      NA
                          4       2012    3.0000  2.9973  0.0039  2.9963  0.0032  2.6160  0.7607
                          5       2013    2.9973  2.9986  0.0019  2.9973  0.0027  2.9966  0.0026
                          6       2014    2.9973  2.9973  0.0000  2.9982  0.0016  2.9973  0.0022", header = TRUE)
```

Talvez você se tenha esquecido da vírgula? As soluções são:

Ordem crescente:

```
dat[order(dat$Med.2),]
```

Ordem descrescente:

```
dat[order(dat$Med.2, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

### Usando dplyr:

Crescente:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% arrange(Med.2)
```

Decrescente:

```
dat %>% arrange(desc(Med.2))
```